# bind doesn't pass down to buttons content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a wpf window defined thus:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="LineStyleDisplay.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>

    <ListBox x:Name="theListView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=TheCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Margin="2" x:Name="LS_button" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource LineStyleTemplate}" Click="LS_button_Click"
                        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=Content, Mode=OneTime}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Background="#FFDFF9FB" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

the linestyledisplay.xaml is defined thus:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PKHL.Clean_Slate.LineStyleCleaner">
<DataTemplate x:Key="LineStyleTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,3,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StyleName}" MinWidth="64" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0,0,0,0" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StyleWeight}" FontSize="9" Padding="0,0,5,0" />
                <Canvas Width="16" Height="9" Background="{Binding StyleColour}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StylePattern}" FontSize="9" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="M: " FontSize="9" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModelLinesUsingStyle}" FontSize="9" Padding="0,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="D: " FontSize="9" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DetailLinesUsingStyle}" FontSize="9" Padding="0,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The problem is the textblock's and canvas in the resourcedictionary don't display the binding information. They just show up as blank. Can someone tell me why the databinding stream is breaking?

Comment: How does `TheCollection` look like? Please provide its declaration, including the element type of the collection.

Comment: _TheCollection_ is an ObservableCollection filled with a custom class that has public properties that return string or int types, nothing special. This class is showing as the Buttons datacontext when I debug. So the break is between the items in the resourcedictionary and the button. I just can't see why.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems to be overly complicated to me to be honest. My suggestion would be to have an implicit data template in place of the ContentType. Something like this:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:MyContentType}">
        <Button>
            <Border>
                <!-- ... -->
            </Border>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

If you don't want that template in that .xaml file, you can move it to the resource dictionary. Like that you have a consistent way to display this kind of data all over your application. In addition, you can bind a ObservableCollection directly to the listboxes ItemSource.

Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the button solved the problem:

```
<ContentPresenter DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=Content, Mode=OneTime}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource LineStyleTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: You should probably note that DataContext is a dependency property with [value inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.100).aspx), which means that child elements down the tree inherit its value from their parent elements. It is therefore not necessary to explicitly set it on each level. All your DataContext bindings are apparently redundant.